# Past simple "We were late for the plane"

Tags: meaning-in-context, past-tense

> We were late for the plane because we had forgotten our passports.

By this sentence is it possible to decide whether they departed or not?

Comment: The sentence doesn't say anything as to whether the speaker(s) departed. It says only that the speaker(s) were late, and it gives a reason for that. Why would you think the sentence says or implies that the speakers departed or didn't?

Comment: The implication is that the speakers did not depart. "Late for the plane" implies that the plane left without them. "We were late for the plane, but the plane was delayed, so we made the flight" is awkward. Normally you would say "We would have been late for the plane, but the plane was delayed, so we made the flight."

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not clear without any further context.

> We were late for the plane because we had forgotten our passports. We had to run all the way from security to the gate.
>
> We were late for the plane because we had forgotten our passports. Fortunately, there was another flight just 2 hours later.

If you want the sentence to indicate that they did **not** fly, use the verb "miss":

> We missed the plane because we had forgotten our passports.

Or use the modifier "too":

> We were *too* late for the plane because we had forgotten our passports.

Comment: Or, "just barely made the plane", for the other case.

Comment: Entirely possible too is "*We were late for the plane because we had forgotten our passports.  We had to wait a week for the next one*."